# Detect unwanted functions (fdescribe, describe.only) as Gulp task

Tags: node.js, jasmine, gulp, mocha.js

How can the usage of unwanted functions in code base be detected in Node, particularly Gulp?

I'm after checking for unintentionally spoiled specs, i.e `ddescribe`/`fdescribe` and `iit`/`fit` for Jasmine or `.only` and `.skip` for Mocha:

```
// should be reported
fdescribe(function () {
  // should not be reported
  it(function () {
    var fit = ...;
    this.fit = ...;
  });

  // should not be reported
  // fit(function () { ... });

  //  should be reported
  xit(function () { ... });

  //  should be reported
  fit(function () { ... });
});
```

---

```
// should be reported
describe.only(function () {
  // should not be reported
  it(function () { ... });

  // should not be reported
  // it.only(function () { ... });

  //  should be reported
  it.skip(function () { ... });

  //  should be reported
  it.only(function () { ... });
});
```

The task should exit with error and output file names and line numbers where listed functions are used.

The commented ones surely don't have to be detected, as well as functions/properties with the same name (most likely `fit`), so simple regexp match is not an option here (like it would be for `console.*`). Some AST-based solution that accepts user-defined function names would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I would solve it on a static analysis step via [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) javascript linting utility. To catch the exclusive/focused mocha specs accidentally left in the codebase, there is a [`no-exclusive-tests` rule](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/no-exclusive-tests.md) implemented in the [`eslint-plugin-mocha` plugin](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha):

> Mocha has a feature that allows you to run tests exclusively by
>   appending `.only` to a test-suite or a test-case. This feature is really
>   helpful to debug a failing test, so you don’t have to execute all of
>   your tests. After you have fixed your test and before committing the
>   changes you have to remove `.only` to ensure all tests are executed on
>   your build system.
>
> *This rule reminds you to remove `.only` from your tests by raising a
>   warning whenever you are using the exclusivity feature.*

If you want to tie the `eslint` run to `gulp` - use the [`gulp-eslint`](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint) plugin.

---

It might also be a good idea to run the `gulp` `eslint` task *before commit* in a git hook. We've used the [`pre-git`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-git) package to install and keep track of the git hooks.

This way the focused or exclusive tests would not get into the codebase in the first place.

Comment: I didn't think about linters for that purpose. I would like to have the AST-based solution for user-defined function names at hand, but just for for test framework globals eslint-plugin-mocha may be what I need. Sadly, it looks like it doesn't support `.skip`.

Comment: @estus good, we've had the same exact problem but with jasmine. We've fixed that with `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-jasmine`, running `grunt eslint` task as a pre-commit git hook - now, after several months using this setup, I can say that it really helps to keep the codebase clean of accidental leftovers like focused specs. Glad to help.

Comment: @estus I think this `eslint-plugin-mocha` rule would warn about skip: https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/no-global-tests.md.

Comment: @estus note that, `ESLint` is quite pluggable, it's not difficult to write custom rules (we've developed several of them for internal purposes). Eslint has a great API and gives you quite a wide window into the AST, nodes and the context: http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a closer look at that. Yes, that's the work suitable for the linter, I already use gulp-eslint in my workflow.